# How to disable password reminder email in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'd like the Password::remind method to respond with the token and not send email to the email address provided. Can I suppress/disable email?

help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can, the best you can do is to make one yourself, using Laravel's way of doing it:

Create a new class:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\DatabaseReminderRepository as DbRepository;

class Reminder {

    public static function create($user)
    {
        $reminders = new DbRepository(DB::connection(), Config::get('auth.reminder.table'), Config::get('app.key'));

        return $reminders->create( $user );
    }

}
```

And use it

```
$user = User::find(2);

echo Reminder::create($user);
```

After that you can check your password_reminders table, you new token will be there:

```
select * from password_reminders;
```